# DotNet + OpenPop library - succeed connect from localhost but fail from production server

Tags: openpop

I have an gmail account, configured to use pop for incoming.
I need to connect and read mail from dot net app using OpenPop

My OpenPop client try to connect to pop.gmail.com with port 995 SSL:

```
MyPop3Client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
```

I do succeed to connect if I run from my localhost server, 
but when trying to connect from production server I get: "Server not found".

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved - it was a firewall program on production server which blocked required port.